# Wait until <script> tag has finished loading to execute another <script> tag, inside jQuery modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are loading an HTML page with jQuery `.modal()`;

In the HTML page, it does something like this:

```
<script src="load a .js file from some external domain"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Trying to call function...');
    function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file();
  });
</script>
```

If have also tried without the doc ready function (and would *prefer* to not have to rely on jQuery):

```
<script src="load a .js file from some external domain"></script>
<script>
    console.log('Trying to call function...');
    function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file();
</script>
```

The problem is that for whatever reason, `function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file()` tries to execute BEFORE the initial `<script>` ever loads and executes.

I can verify this by adding console.log() debugging to both scripts, and I end up with something like this in the Chrome console:

> Trying to call function...
>
> The code in the remote  tag is executing now!

Where-as what I'd expect is the opposite:

> The code in the remote  tag is executing now!
>
> Trying to call function...

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and what I can do to avoid it?

Comment: try adding `<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Trying to call function...');
    function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file();
  });
</script>` after `</html>` tag.

Comment: This is a jquery question, not ajax. $(document).ready executes when your DOM is ready, NOT WHEN YOUR RESSOURCES ARE LOADED. Check out getScript() instead: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: @herezy  I guess maybe I worded this poorly -- eventually I'd like to be able to do this WITHOUT jQuery and make sure it still works. So I'm looking for the most general solution here. I have edited the post to reflect this more clearly.

Comment: @herezy  I'm also not clera how getScript() would help. The callback for that fires after it's loaded, but potentially BEFORE it's execute, which is the same thing that's happening now.

Comment: It's not the same at all. Your script right now is not even executed after your "a.js" is loaded. getScript might be worth exploring, because it enables a relation between a.js and your inline script, something which you don't have at all right now. It's not meant as a definitive complete answer (or else it would be posted as an answer), just a general pointer. Especially since I'm assuming that you have little or no control over the content a.js, as it's the only reason that would explain why your code is organized in such a weird inconvenient way.

Comment: Assuming that `load a .js file from some external domain` loads the function you are looking for directly, you shouldn't see the behaviour you describe. If it starts doing things like dynamically loading different scripts or creating functions dynamically when events fire then you might have problems, but we can't tell what is going on without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something that wait that the js has been executed.

like this :

```
<script>
    // Check if a name is defined
    var isModuleDefined = function(moduleName) {
        var fields = moduleName.split('.'), cur = window;
        for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
            if(typeof cur[fields[i]] === "undefined") return false;
            cur = cur[fields[i]];
        }
        return true;
    };



    var runWhenReady = function(){
        // Wait for the availability of the function
        if (!isModuleDefined("function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file")){
            setTimeout(runWhenReady, 50);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Trying to call function...');
        function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file();
    };
    runWhenReady();

</script>
```

I use this method when i attempt to load a big compressed js file and the callback method is called before that the js was interpreted

Answer (score 0):

The ready function is guaranteed to run when the *DOM* is loaded.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

For what you want, you should probably run your function in the load event

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Did you mean to post two separate links there, or the same link twice...?

Comment: Script elements are blocking. Switching between load and ready shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I've always wondered if it's actually required to be or if it's just a common practice but I never found a definitive source. And if the execution is also required to complete before going on.

Comment: Yes. There are `defer` and `async` attributes floating around to change that behaviour, but if they didn't block, `document.write` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up a race condition, because  tags are loaded asynchronously. When the browser sees the  tag, it starts downloading the source in another thread and continues parsing the rest of the page. So, unless that download happens amazingly fast, your function definition won't exist in time, even with a `$(document).ready`.

What you need is a callback fired by your function definition.

```
var function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file = function() {
    //do stuff here
}
// more code here if you want
call_me_when_function_is_ready_to_run ();
//end of file
```

and in your html page:

```
<script>
    var call_me_when_function_is_ready_to_run = function() {
        console.log('Trying to call function...');
        function_call_defined_in_external_domain_js_file();
    };
</script>
<script src="load a .js file from some external domain"></script>
```

Note that the script order has to change in the HTML because the callback has to be defined before it is potentially called.

Comment: script elements are not loaded asynchronously (the http requests for them might be, but DOM parsing is blocked while they load)